# Load remote html into a container but prevent from running

Tags: jquery, json

I want to pull html from a remote site into a div container using a server side script so I can use jquery to pull values from certain elements on the page. E.g. Meta tags / Page title etc.

Is there a way to prevent the HTML from actually running whilst still being able to use jQuery selectors?

Could I parse the remote content as escapable json?

Comment: by saying *Is there a way to prevent the HTML from actually running?*  do you mean grab the mark up but not display it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the HTML directly into a jQuery object without it being added to your page:

```
var jQueryObjectOfRemoteHtml = $('<div>Literally add the HTML like this</div>');
```

I have put one `div` tag in there - but you could place the whole lot in there and then run jQuery operations against it and never add it to your HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
$.get('yoururl/test.html', function(data) {
    var html = $(data);
    //html is now a queryable jQuery object

    //find a div by id:
    console.log(html.find("#somediv"));

    //iterate all meta tags:
    html.find("meta").each(function(){
        //do your thing here
    });
});
```